# Area between curves using differential equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question goes as follows:

The function $f(x),$ defined for $x \ge 0,$ has the following property: For any real number $a \ge 0,$ the area between the graph of $y = f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le a$ and the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ is equal to the area between the same part of the graph and the $y$-axis. (They mean the red and blue area are equal.)

(a) Find a differential equation that the function $f(x)$ satisfies. (In particular, this equation will involve $f(x)$ and $f'(x).$)

(b) Prove that $f(x) = 2 \sqrt{x} + kx$ for some constant $k.$
[image]

What I've tried so far: I understand the second part, in order to maintain equal areas in the red and blue area, $f(x)$ must be double $y$. The parts I am mostly lost on is proving what $f(x)$ to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equating the incremental areas of the red and blue regions when moving from $x $ to $x + dx$ , we get,

$ (f(x) - \sqrt{x} ) dx = x dy $

So,

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} ( f(x) - \sqrt{x} ) $

So the differential equation is

$ x y' - y = -\sqrt{x} $

Dividing by $x$

$ y' - \dfrac{1}{x}(y) = - x^{-1/2} $

Which is a linear first order differential equation, with an integrating factor

$ e^{ \int -\dfrac{dx}{x} } = x^{-1}$

Multiplying through by the integrating factor

$ \dfrac{ x y' - y }{x^2} = - x^{-3/2} $

The left hand side is the derivative of (y/x) with respect to x, so

$ \dfrac{d}{dx} (y/x) = - x^{-3/2} $

Integrating,

$ y/x = 2 x^{-1/2} + k $

And finally,

$ y = 2 x^{1/2} + k x $

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Note however that it can be made easier by dividing the third formula by $x^2$ and then using the fact that $y'/x - y/x^2 = (y/x)'$. Integration then leads directly to the final result.